# Can't right align items inside of a <ul>. Weird space between item and border

Tags: css

So I'm trying to right align the itens inside of the ul. I want the item to touch the right border.

1. Did some research and tried to use "justify-items: end;"  inside of the grid (container). Didn't work.
2. Tried to use "justify-self: end;" in the right element, also didn't work.
3. Created a flexbox, inside of the `<ul>` , and tried "align-items: flex-end" , also didn't work.

I don't know what to do. Probably can't align because there is a space between the item and the right margin (which I've put a green background for everyone to see), but I dont know where this space come from, also don't know how to remove it. Tried to do margin:0  and padding:0, but it didn't work.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,html{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}


.container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 35% 2fr;
    grid-template-areas: "leftEl rightEl";
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    height: 100%;
    
}


.right{
    grid-column: rightEl;
    justify-self: end; /*not working*/
    border: 3px solid black;
}


ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end; /* not working */
    padding: 0;
}

.li-el{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color: white;
    transform: rotateY(-22deg) rotateX(7deg);
}


.li-el p{
    margin: 1.5rem;
}



.li1{
    background-color: rgba(37, 187, 112);
}

.li2{
    background-color: rgb(154, 169, 168);
}

.li3{
    background-color: rgb(89, 188, 224);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="art1"></div>
    <div class="art2"></div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="right">
            <ul>
                <li class="li-el li1">
                    <p>Pellentesque pretium ullamcorper ullamcorper. Aenean quis accumsan eros. Fusce pretium risus a risus pretium ornare. </p>
                </li>
                <li class="li-el li2">

                    <p>Pellentesque pretium ullamcorper ullamcorper. Aenean quis accumsan eros. Fusce pretium risus a risus pretium ornare. </p>
                </li>
                <li class="li-el li3">

                    <p>Pellentesque pretium ullamcorper ullamcorper. Aenean quis accumsan eros. Fusce pretium risus a risus pretium ornare. </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have (1) the padding of the container (2) the default ul margin

Comment: I'm aware of the padding of the container, I'm only concerned about the black border box. Tried to set the ul margin to zero, nothing changed. =( Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have transformed the li elements to skew their boxes. I added `margin-right: -6px` on them and it bumped them over:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 35% 2fr;
  grid-template-areas: "leftEl rightEl";
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.right {
  grid-column: rightEl;
  justify-self: end;
  /*not working*/
  border: 3px solid black;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  /* not working */
  padding: 0;
}

.li-el {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(-22deg) rotateX(7deg);
  margin-right: -6px;
}

.li-el p {
  margin: 1.5rem;
}

.li1 {
  background-color: rgba(37, 187, 112);
}

.li2 {
  background-color: rgb(154, 169, 168);
}

.li3 {
  background-color: rgb(89, 188, 224);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="right">
    <ul>
      <li class="li-el li1">
        <p>Pellentesque pretium ullamcorper ullamcorper. Aenean quis accumsan eros. Fusce pretium risus a risus pretium ornare. </p>
      </li>
      <li class="li-el li2">

        <p>Pellentesque pretium ullamcorper ullamcorper. Aenean quis accumsan eros. Fusce pretium risus a risus pretium ornare. </p>
      </li>
      <li class="li-el li3">

        <p>Pellentesque pretium ullamcorper ullamcorper. Aenean quis accumsan eros. Fusce pretium risus a risus pretium ornare. </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still don't get it why it is taking that much space... I used the inspection element in the browser for the <li> element and, for a 1280 width screen, the li element is taking up 748px of space, whilst the ul element has 794. So there is more or less 50px of space being allocated without any sort of explanation.